# Uploading an Converting Files In one script

Tags: audio, coldfusion, server-side, cfc, audio-converter

I've written a process for my company which pulls audio files (wav) from a server to their permanent location.  Pretty straight forward using ftp.

The issue now is that we wish to convert these wav files into mp3s.  I was hoping to combine the transfer/upload process and the converting process into one script. So as we move them over, I could process them (while not slowing the transfer rate overall).  Obviously there are technical issues involved as the conversion process is process intensive and we may require a third server that does the actual conversion. Our conversion program that we'll use is LAME.

I'm envisioning something like a multi-threaded application that would use a queue where each thread would handle a portion of that queue of transferring and converting the files.  So thread-A moves 10-30 files, thread-B moves another 10-30 files.  Both A and B move the files to this "conversion box or boxes" and once they've been converted, are than moved to their permanent location.

Would this work out or is there a simpler method?

Comment: Seems a little complex.  The way I envision it is to have a "Download" process, whose sole responsibility is to fetch the files from their origin.  Then, you have a "Conversion" process whose sole responsibility is to convert the file and maybe place it in a 'Completed Files' directory.  Finally, you have a "Transfer" process that polls and copies completed files to their final destination.  This business of having multiple threads essentially doing the same thing will just complicated.  The way I described, each process is compartmentalized and don't need to know anything about each other.

Comment: That's a good point.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jeremy's pointed you in the right direction here.  I'd do this:

1. FTP the files to a staging directory
2. Have a Directory Watcher gateway configured to watch that directory,
   and process incoming files ([a good article on directory
   watchers](http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/using-a-coldfusion-directory-watcher-to-minify-javascript-382))
3. You might want to have some sort of respooling process, or park
   files that failed to convert in another directory (much like the
   `undelivr` directory in ColdFusion's mail subsystem), and log the
   failure so separate action can be taken
4. Stick the converted files in a different directory, and perhaps have
   another directory watcher keep an eye on that to deploy the file, or
   create a record in a DB to reference it, or whatever the next
   workflow step is.